# Symfony2 - form_widget - checkbox separate

Tags: symfony, twig

I have this:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>{{ form_label(form.fees, 'fees' | trans , { 'label_attr': {'class': 'col-sm-3 control-label'} }) }}</legend>
    <div class="large-12 columns fees">
        <br/>
        {{ form_errors(form.fees) }}
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            {{ form_widget(form.fees, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control validate[required]'} }) }}
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

This line:
`{{ form_widget(form.fees, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control validate[required]'} }) }}`

print:

```
<label></label>
<input />
<label></label>
<input />
```

But i need something like this(with wrappers):

```
<div><label></label><input /></div>
<div><label></label><input /></div>
```

Tnx!! :)

Comment: Sounds like [form themes](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#method-1-inside-the-same-template-as-the-form) is what you're looking for. The link chapter I linked points to a method suitable if you want to customize only a specific form (not all of them). To modify all of the forms, scroll down a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you would like to have rows of four checkboxes, that will be something like:

```
{# Wrap span around checkboxes #}
{{ form_label(form.fees) }}
{{ form_errors(form.fees) }}<br>
{% for batch in form.fees|batch(4) %}
    <div class="batchRow">
        {% for option in batch %}
            <div class="yourClassName">
                {{ form_label(option) }}
                {{ form_widget(option) }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Otherwise you can get rid of the batch level.

Answer (score 0):

You can use customize an individual field. for example you have `ProductType` form and your case is fee. So, you can add this line in your top code:

```
{# tell symfony use form theme #}
{% form_theme form _self %}

{# the block customize #}
{% block _product_fees_widget %}
    <div>
        {{ block('form_widget_simple') }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{# print #}
{{ form_widget(form.fees, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control validate[required]'} }) }}
```

for more information, please read this **[FORM THEME](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#how-to-customize-an-individual-field)**

Comment: [`_self` is deprecated since Twig 1.20](http://symfony.com/blog/security-release-twig-1-20-0)